# How to use Enterprise librrary in MVC as a DAL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Is there any fine tutoruial for MVC using Enterprise Library for data access?

Comment: I don't know of any tutorial but you might want to search for 'the data access application block' which is part of entlib.

Comment: @RBaarda  +1. Seems like I am getting much more relevant results.

Comment: @RBaarda Please post you comment as an answer, so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by @Chris my comment on the question posted as an answer:

> I don't know of any tutorial but you might want to search for '**the data access application block**' which is part of entlib.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [very simple article from c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/2236/). The code from there

First of all you need to add a reference for "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll".
Then add a config section in the configuration file.

```
<configSections>
<sectionname="dataConfiguration" 
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" />
</configSections>
```

Here is the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<addname="NorthWNDConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|NORTHWND.MDF;User Instance=true"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<addname="ApplicationServices"
connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @BhargavRao feel free to do so :)